# Google sheets: make count summary (for bar chart) that parses comma separated arrays that already has commas in it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is similar to the question already posted and answered [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138969/how-do-i-make-a-bar-chart-that-parses-comma-separated-arrays-in-google-sheets). The difference is that the options to my multiple choice question already have commas inside them.

I would like to make a count summary so that I can make a bar graph. I have a multiple choice question with answers that have commas **inside** them. For example:

```
Foods I like (select all that apply):

- Fruit (Apples, Oranges)
- Vegetables (Carrots, Corn)
- Meat (Beef, Chicken)
```

The formula `=query({A5:A13},"SELECT Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1")` will give me something like:

```
Fruit (Apples, Oranges) -- 1
Fruit (Apples, Oranges), Vegetables (Carrots, Corn) -- 1
Fruit (Apples, Oranges), Vegetables (Carrots, Corn), Meat (Beef, Chicken) -- 1
```

My expected result (using the same data above) is:

```
Fruit (Apples, Oranges) -- 3
Vegetables (Carrots, Corn) -- 2
Meat (Beef, Chicken) -- 1
```

---

---

The answer posted on the similar question I linked above is:

```
=query(transpose(split(JOIN(",",A5:A13),",",true,true)),"SELECT Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1")
```

This doesn't work for me in this case since it would split the options by `,` would also split each answer into multiple answers... It gives me an output like:

```
Fruit (Apples -- #
Oranges) -- #
Vegetables (Carrots -- #
Corn) -- #
Meat (Beef -- #
Chicken) -- #
```

As you can see, the options for the question are split into multiple options. How can I make a count summary without manually editing the response data?

EDIT: I have made a [test spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1S4awamt0drzecEh3VbeG2dj50V96xxbLwVdpBGSCq2Y/edit?usp=sharing).

---

---

EDIT: Updated with [@zummontt 's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61303015/8871635):

Currently I am using the formula `=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,D3:D7),"), ",")|"),"|")),"SELECT Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1")` and get the output:

```
Fruit (Apples, Oranges) -- 3
Grain, Sweets -- 1
Grains, Fruit (Apples, Oranges) -- 1
Meat (Beef, Chicken) -- 2
Sweets -- 1
Vegetables (Carrots, Corn) -- 3
```

The problems with this output are:

- did not split "Grains" and "Sweets"
- did not split "Grains" and "Fruit (Apples, Oranges)"
- how to get "None (I don't eat food)" to show up if
  it has 0 count?

Comment: Is this what you were looking for `=query({A5:A13},"SELECT Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1")` ? If not, please explain more of expect result

Comment: @zummontt It does not, since the response data I have are responses to a multiple choice question, which means my data is cells that contain multiple options, that are comma separated. I have edited my question and added clarification.

Comment: Hi, can you share the spreadsheet so have a better example on how do you have it and to try it?

Comment: Sure, I have added a link to a test spreadsheet @Kessy

Comment: Have you considered doing it with apps script? It could be more clean and easy to understand than with formulas.

Comment: @Kessy I have not, and I don't have experience with using apps scripts... I'll look into that, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Did you manage to accomplish that? If not, can you update the question with your current situation. If yes, can you post the answer so more people can benefit from it?

Comment: @Kessy I've added the current status with zummontt's solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Abraham, I got side-tracked trying to use SPLIT and REGEXMATCH as well, which I'm not very familiar with, but I think I came up with something very straightforward.  See my answer attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have an answer that works for you.  Rather than splitting the answers apart, I just do a FIND across each answer string for the various food options.  If text is not found in a response, set to BLANK.
Then using COUNT to count up all of the numeric values, gives the sum total.

```
=COUNT(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(FIND(D12,$C$3:$C$7,1),"")))
```

Here, D12 is the first entry from your list of the possible food choices, and C3:C7 is the range of responses.
Effectively doing:

```
=COUNT(ArrayFormula(IFERROR(FIND("Grains",ArrayOfResponses,1),"")))
```

I haven't been able to get this as a single formula to fill the whole table, so you need to copy the formula down, beside each of your food options.

See the sheet/tab Sheet1-GK that I've added to your sample sheet.
Let me know if this helps, or you need something further.

Comment: This is definitely helpful and an acceptable solution, since I do not need to manually edit the response data.

I only have to copy and paste the answer-choices and put this formula for those, that works for me :)

Thank you very much! This was simpler than I thought it'd have to be...

Comment: @Abraham, I'm really glad I was able to come up with a solution for you.  It was a fun challenge for me...!

Answer (score 1):

as I see `),` so I replace `),`  with `)|` by using `SUBSTITUTE()` and to keep `)` display

then use `SPLIT()` from `|`

However it's still case sensitive, when your data is not properly as `"), "`

```
=QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,D2:D),"), ",")|"),"|")),"SELECT Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1")
```

Range D2:D contain

```
Fruit (Apples, Oranges)
Fruit (Apples, Oranges), Vegetables (Carrots, Corn)
Fruit (Apples, Oranges), Vegetables (Carrots, Corn), Meat (Beef, Chicken)
```

I hope this will help

it would be other solution better than this, This solution is what I can come out for now

Comment: That was very helpful! This is very close! However, it's still not complete for me, since I have some options that do not have (...) and still contain commas... This solution successfully did NOT split any answer into multiple answers, which is great! But there were some cells that still contained more than one answer.

Comment: Let me know if I should update my question with your solution and show the output that I want to fix.

Comment: Oh! that's more complex than I thought. I understand your question but kinda impossible for me. However better wait for the experts